# How to calculate the alternating sum of two arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a function "alternatingSum(a)" that takes an array of numbers and returns the alternating sum (where the sign alternates from positive to negative or vice versa).

For example:

```
int[] a = { 5, 3, 8, 4 };
Assert(alternatingSum(a) == 6); // because 5-3+8-4 == 6
```

So far I have tried to take the array and check to see if the index is odd (not including `i=0`) then subtract it from the `i+1`, and if it is even do the same thing except add the two. Am I on the right track with this?

Here is my code:

```
class foo {
    public static int alternatingSum(int[] a){
        int sum=0;
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if (i==0){
                sum+=a[0]-a[1];
            }
            if (i%2 == 0){
                sum+=(a[i]+a[i+1]);
            }
            if (i%2 == 1){
                sum+=(a[i]-a[i+1]);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    } 

    public static void testAlternatingSum(){
        System.out.println("testing code");
        int[] a = { 5, 3, 8, 4 };
        assert (alternatingSum(a) == 6); // because 5-3+8-4 == 6
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        testAlternatingSum();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 3):

#### a `for` loop

I would just keep a `boolean` flag for `even` (and toggle it with every loop iteration). If it's an `even` number, than we're performing addition. But if it's not an `even` number (it's `odd`) then we can perform an [unary negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#Unary_negative_and_positive) operation. That might look something like,

```
int sum = 0;
boolean even = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += even ? a[i] : -a[i];
    even = !even
}
return sum;
```

#### `for-each` loop

and you could also use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and write it like

```
boolean even = true;
int sum = 0;
for (int value : a) {
    sum += even ? value : -value;
    even = !even;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: Thanks! that makes so much more sense that what i was writing haha

Answer (score 0):

Easy to read..

```
int[] alternatingSums(int[] a) {

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
        
        if((i % 2) != 1){
            sum1 += a[i];
        }else{
            sum2 += a[i];
        }
    }

    int[] result = {sum1 , sum2};
    
    return result; 
}
```